# How to copy a value of merged cells to its adjacent cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I need to find a merged cell in the active sheet and copy the value to the adjacent cell. 
I tried to write a macro below but this is not copying the cell value. I am getting `Error 424` in the line `ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Select`

Below is my table:

```
    A       B
 **Merged Cell1**   
 Value1         
 Value2         
 Value3         
 text4          
 text5          
 text6          
 text7          
 text8          
 **Merged Cell3**           
 Value1         
 Value2         
 **Merged Cell4**           
 text4          
 text5          
 text6          
 text1          
 **Merged Cell5**           
 text4          
 text5          
 **Merged Cell5**           
 text
```

```
Sub TestMacro5()
    Dim rcount As Integer
    Dim row As Integer
    Dim col As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    ActiveSheet.Select
    col = 1
    row = 1
    i = 1
    rcount = Application.CountA(Range("A:A"))

    For i = 1 To rcount
        ActiveSheet.Cells(row, col).Select
        If Selection.MergeCells Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 5).Value = ActiveCell.Value
            row = row + 1
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Go through this post [*avoid using select/activesheet*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) to improve your coding. I think that's the only problem you got.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to stay away from using `.Select` to deterine the cell or worksheet that you want to deal with.

```
Dim rcount As Long
Dim rw As Long
Dim cl As Long
With ActiveSheet
    cl = 1
    rw = 1
    rcount = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    For rw = 1 To rcount
        If .Cells(rw, cl).MergeCells Then
            .Cells(rw, cl).Offset(1, 5) = .Cells(rw, cl).Value  '1 row down and 5 columns over ?
            Exit For   'why exit here?
        End If
    Next rw
End With
```

See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for more methods on dealng with cells, cell ranges and worksheets directly.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped. You saved me again.